# Disable Outlook signatures by group policy

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-2003

Is there a way of disabling Outlook signatures for all users/computers via group policy and administrative templates?

We are implementing a third-party centrally managed signature solution and want to turn off all signatures created within Outlook without having to visit each and every workstation on the domain.

We are running Windows Server 2003 with a mix of Outlook 2003 and 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Admin Template (.adm) files for Outlook and importing them into certain object will let you set that setting.  Go to User Config -> Admin Templates (add the files by right-clicking on Admin Templates folder and selecting Add/Remote templates).  Then keep browsing down to Microsoft Outlook 2010 -> Outlook Options -> Mail Format.  There is a key there to disable signatures so Outlook can't use them.

I'm assuming the 3rd party doesn't create Outlook signatures.  If they do, and you just want to block that, let me know and I'll keep digging.

You can download the Files here:

- [Outlook 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=64b837b6-0aa0-4c07-bc34-bec3990a7956)
- [Outlook 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92d8519a-e143-4aee-8f7a-e4bbaeba13e7&displaylang=en)
- [Outlook 2003 SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=ba8bc720-edc2-479b-b115-5abb70b3f490&displaylang=en)